# Apply row and column sum to cell in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can someone suggest an easy way of achieving the result bellow.

Data:

```
data = np.array([
['','A','B'],
['Yes',44,19],
['No',116,128]
])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],    
                  index=data[1:,0],    
                  columns=data[0,1:])

df:
           A    B
    Yes   44   19
    No   116  128
```

For each cell, I'd like to multiply the sum of the row total by the column total and divide by the table total (at this point I don't care about the call's value), so cell Yes\A would be:

63 * 160 / 307  = 32.83

these values come from:

63 = 44 + 19

160 = 44 + 116

307 = 44 + 19 + 116 + 128

any easy way to do so?

Thanks

Edit.
Full desired result (also, this method should work regardless of the number of rows and columns in the dataframe...which could be different)

```
32.83    30.17
127.17   116.83
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtue of this solution compared to the ones above is that it fits in one line, but I'm afraid that's probably where it ends.

```
df.apply(lambda r: df.sum()[r.name]*df.sum(1)[r.index]/df.sum().sum())
```

Comment: Yes, apply is bound to be slower than matrix multiplication.

Comment: @jezrael's solution should probably be the accepted one. It's faster and ultimately easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) and with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) `Dataframes` created with `Series` by [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = df.astype(int)

print (df.sum(1).to_frame())
       0
Yes   63
No   244

print (df.sum().to_frame())
     0
A  160
B  147

print (df.sum(1).to_frame().dot(df.sum().to_frame().T).div(df.sum().sum()))
              A           B
Yes   32.833876   30.166124
No   127.166124  116.833876
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,10)))
df.columns = list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
print (df)

In [293]: %timeit (df.apply(lambda r: df.sum()[r.name]*df.sum(1)[r.index]/df.sum().sum()))
100 loops, best of 3: 14.1 ms per loop

In [294]: %timeit (df.sum(1).to_frame().dot(df.sum().to_frame().T).div(df.sum().sum()))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 ms per loop
```

Comment: same for yes `A` and `B` ?

Comment: Yes, it was not easy. Please check answer.

Comment: @SebastianWozny - Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll want to cast the values in your DataFrame to ints (or floats): `df=df.applymap(int)`.

Then you can get the sums for each column and row with the `.sum()` function.
You'll lose the shape of the DataFrame here (you'll end up with two 1-D arrays), so that needs rebuilding.

Then you can add the two and divide by the total sum.

All of this together gives:

```
df= df.applymap(int)

rowsums = pd.concat([df.sum(axis=1)] * 2, ignore_index=True, axis=1)
colsums = pd.concat([df.sum(axis=0)] * 2, ignore_index=True, axis=1).transpose()

colsums.index = rowsums.index
rowsums.columns = colsums.columns

newdata = colsums * rowsums
newdata = newdata.divide(df.sum().sum())
```

This results in:

```
newdata:
              A           B
Yes   32.833876   30.166124
No   127.166124  116.833876
```

Answer (score 1):

Really tricky:

My (probably suboptimal solution):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = np.array([
    ['','A','B'],
    ['Yes',44,19],
    ['No',116,128]
])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:]).apply(pd.to_numeric,axis=0)
orig = df.copy()
df['rowsum']=df.sum(axis=1)
df.loc['colsum',:]=df.sum(axis=0)
rowsums = df.copy()
rowsums['A'] = rowsums['rowsum']
rowsums['B'] = rowsums['rowsum']
colsums = df.copy()
colsums.loc['Yes',:] = colsums.loc['colsum',:]
colsums.loc['No',:] = colsums.loc['colsum',:]
print(rowsums.multiply(colsums).div(orig.sum().sum()))
```

Result:

```
                 A           B  rowsum
Yes      32.833876   30.166124    63.0
No      127.166124  116.833876   244.0
colsum  160.000000  147.000000   307.0
```